# React native make button fixed to text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, button, fixed

I'm new to React Native and right now I'm doing my first app. The idea of the app is when you press the button a random text will show upp (taken from my data.json). I would like my button to be at a fixed position even though my texts are different length (and therefore different heights). I want it to be about 25-33 % up from the bottom of the screen and as I wrote, stay at the same place even though the text is moving. How can I do that? :)

Here are my code "Training.js":

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Vibration } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const TouchButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  alignSelf: center;
  alignItems: center;
  justifyContent: center;
  padding: 10px;
  marginBottom: 0px;
  width: 160px;
  borderRadius: 15px;
  backgroundColor: #ff8300;
  border: 2px #ff8300;
`
const ButtonText = styled.Text`
  textAlign: center;
  fontSize: 20px;
  fontWeight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  alignItems: center;
  color: #ffad57;
`
const Title = styled.Text`
  width: 300px;
  fontSize: 45px;
  margin: 25px;
  marginBottom: 100px;
  color: #ff8300;
  fontWeight: bold;
  textAlign: center;
  justifyContent: center;
  alignItems: center;
`
export const Training = ({activitiesArray}) => {

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState("")

  const getActivity = () => {
    const theActivity = activitiesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * activitiesArray.length)]
    setActivity(theActivity.activity)
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Title>
        {activity}
      </Title>
      <TouchButton onPress={() => {
      getActivity(); 
      Vibration.vibrate();}}>
        <ButtonText>Vad ska jag träna idag?</ButtonText>
      </TouchButton>
    </View>
  )
};
```

And here are "App.js":

```
import React from 'react'
import data from './data.json'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { Training } from './components/Training'

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Training activitiesArray={data.training}/>
    </Container>
  )
  }

  const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  backgroundColor: #ffad57;
  justifyContent: center;
  alignItems: center;
`

export default App
```

Comment: If I understand correctly,you must TouchButton style change to `justifyContent: center;alignItems: flex-end;marginBottome:30;`

Comment: Hi Amir! Thanks for the help :) When I change the styling according to your comment, the only thing that happens is the button text goes to the right (flex-end) but the button itself is still jumping around depending on the text length of the text above the button.